# Show divergence of $f_k(x):=\sin(kx)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

> Show divergence of $f_k(x):=\sin(kx)$, where $x\neq m\pi$ an $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

---

A quick and elegant approach would be to assume (pointwise) convergence of $(f_k)$ and to notice that this would imply convergence of $\cos(xk)$ as well. Then, \begin{align*}
&\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sin(x)=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sin(xk-x(k+1))\\
&=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}(\sin(xk)\sin(x(k+1))+\cos(xk)\cos(x(k+1)))\\
&=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sin^2(xk)+\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\cos^2(xk)=1,\end{align*} which is a contradiction.

---

However, we must find a different way to prove this. Our professor gave us a hint and said we should start as follows:

Assume that both limits $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sin(xk)=s$ and $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\cos(xk)=c$ exist. Then for any $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2>0$ there exists a $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k>n_0$ we have
\begin{align*}
&\epsilon_1>|\sin(x(k+1))-s|=|\sin(xk)\cos(x)+\sin(x)\cos(xk)-s|\\
&\geq \Big||\sin(x)\cos(xk)|-|\sin(xk)\cos(x)-s|\Big|\\
&\\
&\epsilon_2>|\cos(xk)-c|.
\end{align*}
If we choose $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ in a clever way it will produce a contradiction.

---

I have already tinkered with $\epsilon_1:=\sin(x)$, $\epsilon_1:=|c-s|$, etc... and some other values but it didn't get me nowhere.

Maybe someone sees how to set the $\epsilon$'s and to find some clever bounds?

Comment: _Why_ would convergence of $\sin(kx)$ imply convergence of $\cos(kx)$??

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich if $\sin(kx)$ converges pointwise then $\sin^2(kx)$ also converges. By $\cos^2(xk)=1-\sin^2(xk)$ it follows that $\cos^2(xk)$ converges and we also know the identity $\cos(2(xk))=\cos^2(xk)-\sin^2(xk)$. So $\cos(xk)$ must converge.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, oh I think I did a mistake in the beginning it should be \begin{align*}
&\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\underline{\textbf{cos}}(x)=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\underline{\textbf{cos}}(xk-x(k+1))\\
&=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}(\sin(xk)\sin(x(k+1))+\cos(xk)\cos(x(k+1)))\\
&=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sin^2(xk)+\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\cos^2(xk)=1.\end{align*}